# Understanding the weighted cross-entropy method of u-net

Tags: neural-networks, image-processing, computer-vision, cross-entropy, image-segmentation

I am trying to implement the weight-cross entropy mentioned in [unet](https://lmb.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/people/ronneber/u-net/)
paper to counter the class-imbalances. I am not really able to understand how they are exactly implementing the weight-cross entropy.
Quoting the paper-

[image]

> where $\ell: Ω \to {1,...,K}$ is the true label of each pixel and $w : Ω → \mathbb{R}$
> is a weight map that we introduced to give some pixels more importance
> in the training.

I have the calculated weighted function w(x) but I am not really able to understand how the modified cross-entropy is being calculated here.

Is it just by passing now the weighted function instead of the labels in regular cross-entropy  or is it by multiplying the weighted function with the output of product of log of target and labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard unweighted cross-entropy loss is
$$
\sum_{\mathbf{x} \in \Omega} \log p_{\ell(\mathbf{x})}(\mathbf{x}).
$$
The only difference in the weighted loss $E$ is that you have a set of multiplicative coefficients $w(\mathbf{x})$ that rescale the pointwise log-losses. The overall effect is that some pixels are considered more important to correctly classify.

Comment: Thank You, now this may not be the part of the question and I could post another one if you want but how do you suggest I should incorporate w(x) in the loss. I am trying to do in this way - `loss = weight_map * criterion(output,target)`